# How implement javafx label value change listener

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

how call the listener when Label text changed

```
 Label myLabel= new Label("text1");
```

if i change the text

```
myLabel.settext("text2");
```

There is any listener so that i can perform this

```
myLabel.LISTENER{
System.out.println("Label Text Changed");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

well i found the answer after some rnd 
here is code

```
myLabel.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1) {
               System.out.println("Label Text Changed");
            }
        });
```